# How to display all prices and sizes in one web page (without need to selecting size)

Tags: configurable-product

any Magento master can help me with creating a page with all prices and sizes in one web page (without need to selecting size), such as what's in this website:http://www.selleckchem.com/products/CAL-101.html ? Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the configurable swatches and use them, then you see everything at once:

[image]